# How to use django's manage.py sql* commands with mysql

Tags: mysql, django, django-admin

How are the sql* commands meant to be used? They just output sql, so is there an elegant way to pass it to mysql? `./manage.py sqlindexes [app]` gives me the mysql code - do I just note it down and then type it in? (edit: erm...copy and paste for others. heh.)

Pardon my ignorance, and please let me know if there's a completely different but better way of using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe it to the dbshell command like so:

```
python manage.py sqlindexes my_app | python manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something!

Comment: @sdolan I couldn't find this in the django-admin official documentation. Did you find this somewhere documented? Where?

Comment: @SantiagoAgüero: I'm not sure if it's documented anywhere.  It's just using unix principles to pipe output into a script.